# A problem with Cantor's continuum hypothesis

Tags: set-theory

If CH isn't true, this means $$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2\:.$$
Does this imply:
$$2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_3$$
or does the CH hold only for $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$?
Thanks

Comment: Why should $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$ if CH fails?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, CH just says that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, so its failure just says that $2^{\aleph_0}\ne\aleph_1$. We know that $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\aleph_1$, but it’s consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}$ be any cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$ such that $\alpha\ge 1$ and $\operatorname{cf}\alpha>\omega$. In particular, $2^{\aleph_0}$ could be $\aleph_n$ for any $n>1$.

If $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, $2^{\aleph_1}$ would have to be at least $\aleph_2$, but it could be much bigger. For instance, it’s consistent that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ and $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_{17}$.

Answer (score 15):

The negation of the Continuum Hypothesis does not entail that there is only *one* infinity strictly between the natural numbers and the real numbers.  In fact, given any any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ there is a cardinal $\lambda \geq \kappa$ such that $\text{ZFC} + 2^{\aleph_0} = \lambda$ is consistent (assuming the consistency of ZFC itself, of course).

Even if we assume that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$, it could still be that $2^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$ -- this happens, for example, under the [Proper Forcing Axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom), or more simply under the assumption of [Martin's Axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom) with $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$.  (The Proper Forcing Axiom is a strengthening of Martin's Axiom -- well, formally a strengthening of $\text{MA} ({\aleph_1})$ -- which fixes the size of the continuum at $\aleph_2$.)

On the other hand, we can have $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$ and $2^{\aleph_1} > \aleph_3$.  Very similar techniques for showing the consistency of $\neg \text{CH}$ can be applied to give the above.

The most general statement in this realm is [Easton's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) which essentially says that except for certain basic restrictions, the function $\aleph_\alpha \mapsto 2^{\aleph_\kappa}$ can be consistently arbitrary.